# Reporting feature for a small MVC App, VS 2015

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, reporting

I want to deploy a small fleet management asp.net mvc app (made for ~80 cars), in order to have cost transparency for each car (not a big app), on Azure.
The app offers the client the option to enter all their data (companies -> cars -> bills -> parts/services -> distributors). 
I want now to implement a reporting feature, that has filters like: date interval, car and distributor, in order for the client to be able to generate reports about the cost per car/s or with certain distributor in a time period.

I've search far and wide on the web and read different solutions which generated confusion in my head. What would the best reporting solution be, for my small app? 
As you can probably tell, I'm a newbie in asp.net app development and would appreciate a specialists advise. Thx

Comment: if the reports are simple you can make them within your app itself like a big datagrid with all the columns and so on. If you are okay to develop SSRS reports you can do that (given that db is sql server) and render those reports on your page. it won't work on MVC but will on webforms. Or  you can explore Powerbi reports which can be linked to a web app or viewed separately.

Comment: Thx for the advice. Knew about SSRS and the datagrid solutions. Will look into PowerBI, looks really neat at first glance. Hopefully I find how to's for the filters. Thx again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at PowerBI embedded. You can use the standard PowerBI editor and serve the reports directly inside your application.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/power-bi-embedded/